# invalid pkt-len - AWS CodeBuild failing on DOWNLOAD_SOURCE from CodeCommit

Tags: aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I am running this error during the "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE" phase in CodeBuild:

"invalid pkt-len found"

No other information is provided. I have tried various things to rule out problems.

a) The CodeCommit repo clones successfully, and appears to be fully functional.

b) Building from an earlier revision on this CodeCommit repository that had previously built successfully now throw this error -- Fails with same error message

b) Building from a separate CodeCommit repository with a separate CodeBuild project that has previously built successfully AND has no new commits -- Fails with same error

c) A brand new CodeBuild project and CodeCommit repo -- Does not fail

d) Building the same CodeBuild job that fails, with a zip file (of the same code base) as source instead of CodeCommit, and it does not fail.

Comment: What AWS region are you having this issue?

Comment: both the project and repo are in us-east-1

Comment: Could you start a thread on the [AWS CodeBuild forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230)? We'd like to look into this. Thanks!

Comment: yep will do, i had tried earlier but it had me waiting for a grace period before i could post

Comment: it is now posted here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=278671

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in Codebuild. Turned out, I was using a URL of a sub-folder in the repository. Since it was not a proper Git repo URL, it was throwing an invalid pkt len error. I hope this helps somebody who stumbles onto the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from AWS - this was an issue on their end, which they have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I get this `invalid pkt-len found` error when I've added a new user to our git server (GOGS/Gitea), and they're using SSH URLs but they don't yet have permission to the repo they're requesting.

```
failed to checkout and determine revision: unable to clone 'ssh://git@git-ssh.mygiteahost.lan/username/my-git-repo': invalid pkt-len found
```

Once I've granted the user access to the repo it works as expected.